# PeopleEditor in usercontrol (Visual webpart) misbehave in if (!IsPostBack)-SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a PeopleEditor in usercontrol (Visual webpart). I try to set the value of PeopleEditor field on page load through below code.
But it is empty, and it works fine other than if (!IsPostBack) part.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

      PeopleEditor box1 = (PeopleEditor)GridViewMatrix.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("PeopleEditorApprover");
      box1.CommaSeparatedAccounts="domain\user";
}



  <spuc:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditor1" runat="server" Width="100%" class="fieldName" CommaSeparatedAccounts='<%# Bind("Approver")%>'
                   AllowEmpty="true" MultiSelect="false" SelectionSet="User,SecGroup,SPGroup"  Font-Size="Medium"/>
```

Any solution?